# Replace Everything After the 3rd Occurrence of a Character if Present

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here is what I am trying to do:

Given a string, if the string starts with "/plan", I want to remove everything after the third occurrence of the '/' character — assuming there is a third occurrence, which there may not be. If it begins with "/plan", but has fewer than 3 '/' characters, the regex should return the string as is.

Additionally, if the string doesn't begin with "/plan", the string can be returned as is. Here are some sample inputs and outputs:

```
"" returns ""
"/foo" return "/foo"
"/plan/123" returns "/plan/123"
"/plan/123/4567" returns "/plan/123"
"/plan/123/4567/89010" returns "/plan/123
```

Ideally, I would like to do this entirely through a regex, but given some of the requirements, I realize that it might not be easily accomplished.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 What is the point of that lookahead?

Comment: @Paulpro - oops, should be `^(?(?=/plan)/plan/[^/]*|[\s\S]*`. Supposed to be an [if-else regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), which will match the first expression if it begins with /plan, else it will match anything. Not sure if it's compatible with javascript though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way using a regular expression and `replace`:

```
var str = /* ... */;
str = str.replace(/^(\/plan\/[^\/]+)\/.*$/, '$1');
```

That does this:

1. Capture:

   - Match `/plan` at start of string
   - ...followed by `/`
   - ...followed by one or more non-`/`
2. Match a following `/` followed by anything to end of string
3. Replace the full match with the first capture group

(And if there's no match, there's no replacement.)

Testing: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/imoyit/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/imoyit/1/edit)

```
var tests = [
    {test: "", expect: ""},
    {test: "/foo", expect: "/foo"},
    {test: "/plan/123", expect: "/plan/123"},
    {test: "/plan/123/4567", expect: "/plan/123"},
    {test: "/plan/123/4567/89010", expect: "/plan/123"}
  ];

var index, test, result;
for (index = 0; index < tests.length; ++index) {
  test = tests[index];
  result = test.test.replace(/^(\/plan\/[^\/]+)\/.*$/, '$1');
  if (result === test.expect) {
    display("OK: " + test.test + " => " + result);
  }
  else {
    display("FAIL: " + test.test + " => " + result);
  }
}
```

Results:

```
OK: =>
OK: /foo => /foo
OK: /plan/123 => /plan/123
OK: /plan/123/4567 => /plan/123
OK: /plan/123/4567/89010 => /plan/123
```

Comment: how this will work in case of `java`

Comment: @I'm_Pratik - It's been a **long** time since I did regular expressions in Java, but you'd use either [`String~replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) or [`Pattern` and/or `Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

Comment: Agreed but how $1 will be replaced with `String.replaceAll`, any idea?

Comment: @I'm_Pratik - It's covered by the linked documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Without a Regex you can do it using simple string splits:

```
function planReplace(str) {
    var split = str.split('/');
    if (split.length < 2) return str;
    if (split[1] === 'plan') return "/" + split[1] + "/" + split[2];
    //this line can even be shorter, but it would use a bit more memory:
    //if (split[1] === 'plan') return split.splice(0, 3).join('/');
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `(^/plan/[^/]*).*$` like so:

```
var str = "/plan/123/4567/89010";
str.replace(/(^\/plan\/[^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
```